# Functional Analysis by Rudin, Chapter $10$, Exercise $20$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, spectral-theory

This is the exercise:

> Suppose $x\in A$, $x_n\in A$, and $\lim x_n=x$. Suppose $\Omega$ is
>   an open set in $\mathbb C$ that contains a component of $\sigma(x)$.
>   Prove that $\sigma(x_n)$ intersects $\Omega$ for all sufficiently
>   large $n$. (This strengthens Theorem 10.20.)
>
> Hint: If
>   $\sigma(x)\subset\Omega\cup\Omega_0$, where $\Omega_0$ is an open
>   set disjoint from $\Omega$, consider the function $f$ that is $1$ in
>   $\Omega$, and $0$ in $\Omega_0$.

According to Rudin's hint, we can define $f\in
H(\Omega\cup\Omega_0)$ as follows:
$$
f(\lambda) = \left \{\begin{array}{lll}
  1 &  \ \ \ \ \lambda\in \Omega\\
  0  & \ \ \ \ \lambda\in \Omega_0\\
  \end{array}\right.
$$
And then by symbolic calculus we have
$$
\tilde{f}(x) = \left \{\begin{array}{lll}
  e &  \ \ \ \ \sigma(x)\subset \Omega\\
  0  & \ \ \ \ \sigma(x)\subset \Omega_0\\
  \end{array}\right.
$$
For the $x\in A$ that $x_n\rightarrow x$, we have
$$\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{f}(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\tilde{f}(x_n),$$
meaning $\{\tilde{f}(x_n)\}$ as a sequence in $A$ converges to
$\tilde{f}(x)$. So for a large enough $n$;
$$\sigma\big(\tilde{f}(x_n)\big)\cap\sigma\big(\tilde{f}(x)\big)\neq\emptyset.$$
And by spectral mapping theorem;
$$f\big(\sigma(x_n)\big)\cap f\big(\sigma(x)\big)\neq\emptyset,$$
$$f\big(\sigma(x_n)\big)\cap \{0,1\}\neq\emptyset.$$
So we are forced to have only one of these three possibilities;

1) $f\big(\sigma(x_n)\big)=\{0,1\}$

2) $f\big(\sigma(x_n)\big)=\{1\}$

3) $f\big(\sigma(x_n)\big)=\{0\}$

The third case never happens. Because if it happens by the
definition of $f$, we can conclude for any large $n$ that
$$\sigma(x_n)\subset\Omega_0,$$
in which by tending $n$ to infinity, we get the following
contradiction;
$$\sigma(x)\subset\Omega_0.$$
In the first and second cases, there will be at least one
$\lambda\in \sigma(x_n)$ such that $f(\lambda)=1$ which by
definition simply means $\sigma(x_n)$ intersects $\Omega$.

Is this true? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is meant by $\sigma(x)$?

Comment: It means the spectrum of $x$.

Comment: Actually $\sigma(x)=\{\lambda\in {\mathbb C}: \lambda e - x\ is\ not\
invertible\}$.

Comment: Can you also tell us what is $A$ (or what kind of objects are $x_n$ and $x$)?

Comment: They are unknown. The only thing we know is that we have an ordinary Banach algebra.